# C# naming conventions for acronyms

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Regarding C# naming for acronyms, if I was writing a library related to the Windows API is there any strong convention toward either WindowsApi or WindowsAPI or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

There is a convention, and it specifies initial uppercase, the rest lowercase, for all acronyms that are more than 2 characters long. Hence `HttpContext` and `ClientID`.

Comment: Id - is preferable capitalization. "Two other terms that are in common usage are in a category by themselves, because they are common slang abbreviations. The two words "Ok" and "Id" (and they should be cased as shown) are the exceptions to the guideline that no abbreviations should be used in names". "Framework Design Guidelines" 2nd edition, p.44.

Comment: Someone noted that if ID stood for "Identifying Datum" (rather than "Identifier"), ID would be OK again. Sorry, Ok again.

Comment: @Sergey Teplyakov Microsoft guidelines says to use Pascal only for abbreviations more than 2 characters. In the case of ID and OK, all caps is okay, however HTML becomes Html. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: @smdrager: to be fair, this is only explicitly recommended for acronyms, not abbreviations.

Comment: @smdrager: FDG says that those two are exceptions for this rule. You could open this book on p.44 and take a look at those exceptions yourself:)

Comment: It can be noted that Microsoft themselves don't follow this convention very strictly. For example they use **Db**Context in some places while using **DB**Null in other.

Comment: `DBNull` is much older than `DbContext`; the common practice now is to only capitalize the first letter of an acronym; even if it's only two letters long. -- Even some of the SharePoint stuff is now "Sp". -- The "two letters long" exception to acronym naming is becoming archaic, and at best, is now optional (if not completely deprecated). -- Also, re: "Ok", you should really avoid abbreviations in member names; spell it out as "Okay". -- It's fine in the UI to still show "OK", but, in the code, it should be "Okay".

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 DB isnt exactly an acronym, more like an abbreviation or a shortcut, much like `Id`, so more correct IMO would be `DbNull` rather than `DBNull`. Database, SharePoint etc are not multiple words as such. [Latest doc explicitly say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for real acronyms of two letters, both letters should be uppercase. E.g. `IOStream`. I find it odd to read though. We have interface of such a class and now it would read `IIOStream` :/

Comment: @nawfal And here I am struggling with naming my UIDtos.

Comment: It's usu. better to mirror natural language in both IT Ids and structure of the code (relative to the specs assuming it wouldn't result in significant dupe code / performance issues), but for IT Ids (obviously other than those where space/dash/underscore can and are typically used to separate words / acronyms), your choice to avoid the "significant cost" of using space/dash /underscore means you must also "pay the price" by proper-casing acronyms, and it's better to do so consistently (even if they're separated by a lower case word/digit, "only" 2 chars, "well known", other "excuse", etc.).

Comment: Note that "Id" is specifically used as the correct PascalCase rendering in the [official capitalization docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#capitalizing-compound-words-and-common-terms)

Comment: Check out .NET docs thinks about conventions. Pay attention to RSA and Aes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption .

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 " the common practice now is to only capitalize the first letter of an acronym;" do you know the reference from which your quote is taken?

Comment: Just to complicate things more, neither HTTP, ID, or OK are actual acronyms according to the definition: An acronym needs to be read as a word and not by spelling its letters (such as NASA and UNICEF).

Comment: Is worth noting that `ClientID` would be read as "Client Identification Document", instead of "Client Identifier" (`ClientId`)

Moreover, a driver license in itself is an "Identification Document" of sorts (`ID`), whereas the unique identifier inside it is the "Driver's license Identifier", hence the `ID.Id`

Answer (score 72):

"[Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)" 2nd edition by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams pp.40-42

**3.1.2 Capitalizing Acronyms**

**DO** capitalize both characters on two-character acronyms, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.

```
System.IO
public void StartIO(Stream ioStream)
```

**DO** capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.

```
System.Xml
public void ProcessHtmlTag(string htmlTag)
```

**DO NOT** capitalize any of the characters of any acronyms, whatever their length, at the beginning of a camel-cased identifier.

Comment: I always get a headache if I see this strange "capitalize 2 letter acronyms" rule. It looks like Microsoft realized System.IO was named wrong and decided to make a rule around it. But how to name the identifier of Microsoft Visual Studio? MSVSID? I Say MsVsId would have been a lot better/more consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't follow their own naming conventions. Look at the use of Dto in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: Does anyone know why on Earth the 2-letter rule came about?  What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @rory.ap  - I think it is rooted in advice from the Chicago Manual of Style from 20+ years ago. I remember seeing it in a hardcopy that a tech writer had before, but no idea if its still in there. Also maybe to avoid conflicting meaning with the word "Id" which may seem obscure today was actually a small part of pop culture at the time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Got_Id

Answer (score 28):

Old question, new answer.

According to [.NET 4 Capitalization Rules for Acronyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229043(v=vs.100)#capitalization-rules-for-acronyms):

> **Do capitalize both characters of two-character acronyms, except the
>   first word of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A property named `DBRate` is an example of a short acronym (`DB`) used as
>   the first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named
>   `ioChannel` is an example of a short acronym (`IO`) used as the first word
>   of a camel-cased identifier.
>
> **Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more
>   characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A class named `XmlWriter` is an example of a long acronym used as the
>   first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named `htmlReader`
>   is an example of a long acronym used as the first word of a
>   camel-cased identifier.
>
> **Do not capitalize any of the characters of any acronyms, whatever
>   their length, at the beginning of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A parameter named `xmlStream` is an example of a long acronym (`xml`) used
>   as the first word of a camel-cased identifier. A parameter named
>   `dbServerName` is an example of a short acronym (`db`) used as the first
>   word of a camel-cased identifier.

Answer (score 23):

Check Microsoft's official docs on [Naming Guidelines & Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#capitalization-rules-for-identifiers):

> To differentiate words in an identifier, capitalize the first letter of each word in the identifier. Do not use underscores to differentiate words, or for that matter, anywhere in identifiers. There are two appropriate ways to capitalize identifiers, depending on the use of the identifier:
>
> - *PascalCasing*
> - *camelCasing*
>
> The *PascalCasing* convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following examples:
>
> - `PropertyDescriptor`
> - `HtmlTag`
>
> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier:
>
> - `IOStream`
>
> The *camelCasing* convention, used only for parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word except the first word, as shown in the following examples. As the example also shows, two-letter acronyms that begin a camel-cased identifier are both lowercase.
>
> - `propertyDescriptor`
> - `ioStream`
> - `htmlTag`
>
> **✓ DO** use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.
>
> **✓ DO** use camelCasing for parameter names.

Comment: That document is for .NET 1.1.

Comment: I don't see what difference that makes? It's not like they changed conventions between each version or anything.

Comment: There _is_ a second edition of the design guidelines book. I haven't compared to determine that there are no changes at all in naming.

Comment: Fair enough :) but my point was that surely it can't have changed that much that the old naming conventions are completely deprecated.

Comment: .NET 4.5 guidelines relating to capitalization: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Microsoft's practices have changed over time. -- Albeit subtly. -- As others have pointed out, "DBNull" from .NET 1.1, versus "DbContext" in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 9):

I've heard that you should avoid abbreviations, so it would become `WindowsApplicationProgrammingInterface`, then.

More seriously (folks seem to be mis-reading the above, despite the quote below), [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Naming#Classes_and_Structures) says:

> Any acronyms of three or more letters should be Pascal case, not all caps.

Since API is considered a well-known acronym, the name `WindowsApi` is the one to pick if you want to follow the guidelines.

Comment: Abbreviations are ok if they are well-known within the domain. API is well-known within programming.

Comment: +1. The Framework Guidelines book recommends that you either avoid abbreviations or acronyms or use PascalCase. I would suggest WindowsApi. Example from the framework: Uri, UriBuilder HtmlDecode.

Comment: @John: Yeah, I was being a bit tongue-in-cheek on that one. :)

Comment: @unwind - does that mean we can use html instead of HyperTextMarkupLanguage?

Comment: -1: from Framework Design Guidelines: "In general, it is important to avoid using acronyms in identifier names unless they are in common usage and are immediately understandable to anyone who might use the framework. For example, HTML, XML, and IO are all well understood, but less well-known acronyms should definitely be avoidable". API - is commonly used and immediately understandable acronym.

Comment: @Larry: Yes, and AjaxJson instead of AsynchronousJavascriptAndExtensibleMarkupLanguageJavascriptObjectNotation ;)

Answer (score 4):

Its personal preference. But .NET would use `WindowsApi`. It is akin to the naming of `TcpClient`.

Answer (score 4):

It's all just personal (or organizational) preference. As long as you're consistent, you'll be ok.

The .NET Framework itself would use WindowsApi.

Comment: This. Just had an example where a business acronym of APP has been used as "App" and now looks like an abbreviation of "Application" rather than it's actual meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at FxCop too. It's a nice utility that will help with issues like this.