# Why is ASCII named in upper-case?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Why is ASCII not written as "Ascii" when it's pronounced as a word?

I understand that only the first letter of acronyms containing three characters or more should be capitalised.

Is ASCII not an acronym? I've never heard anyone spell out A - S - C - I - I when they say it.

**EDIT**

In fact, a number of classes in the System.Text namespace does not seem to follow this convention, although I can't think of anywhere else capitalision is retained for acronyms with three characters or more in the .NET Framework.

System.Text.UTF7Encoding

System.Text.UTF8Encoding

System.Text.UTF32Encoding

Surely these are anomalies that don't follow the convension.

Comment: Framework Design Guidelines 2nd edition by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams p40-p42, according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2109419/2707705

Comment: What about AIDS, NATO, ANSI, MPAA, HTML, IEEE, USSR, ... Your common rule seems to have many exceptions.

Comment: Here's what my understanding of an acronym is. I'm of the understanding that ASCII should also be deemed one of them. http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/abbreviations/abbreviations-acronyms-and-initialisms-revisited/

Comment: Please comment when you mark down my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ASCII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is an acronym.  The fact that it is normally *pronounced* as a word does not change that.

However, questions about why words are written / spelled / pronounced in particular ways ... or what they mean ... are ultimately fruitless.  English is a *natural* language that evolves as it is used.

For example:

- words like "radar" and "laser" started out as acronyms and evolved into regular words
- the word "xerox" started as a brand name ("Xerox" (TM)) and has evolved into a regular word<sup>1</sup>
- the word "quantum" started out in Latin, was adopted in scientific english to mean one thing ("the smallest unit / discrete step") and then was transitioned into normal usage with almost the opposite meaning ... as in "making a quantum leap".

<sup>1 - ... despite the best efforts of Xerox Inc's lawyers!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox#Trademark</sup>

---

Yes there are various guidelines for how you are *supposed* to write things in formal documents, but they are just guidelines.  In real human-to-human communication, people use words how they see fit.

In Java source code, the convention is that acronyms should be all uppercase.  However, sometimes that gives results are unpleasing or difficult to understand; e.g. when you need to combine two acronyms in a classname, and the rules say that you can't put an underscore between them.  My advice is to embed the acronym as all uppercase, except when it "doesn't work" ... and *you* be the judge of what works.

Answer (score 2):

> ASCII abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange

([source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

It's uppercase because it's an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is an acronym for **American Standard Code for Information Interchange**, so it is in Uppercase. check Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)